# How can I get the weights from a neural network and ensure they are still trainable?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to train a neural network with an objective function made up of error and regularisation.

In order to do the regularisation, I want to get all of the weights as a 1D tensor (call this tensor `weights`), perform some operations, and add this to the objective function. How do I get the weights so that I can continue to train them?

So far, I have tried:

1. Using tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name() - when I calculate gradients with respect to `weights`, the Error term gradient is always `None`.
2. Using tf.get_variable() - as above, the Error term gradient is always `None`
3. Using the trainable_weights attribute of the layers - the trainable_weights attribute returns an empty list.

The regularisation I am hoping to run is a Gaussian Mixture Model, with the GMM parameters themselves also being trained.

For example, for the third attempt, my code is:

```
# Here I create the layers
layers = []
for L in range(len(units)):
    layer = tf.layers.Dense(units=units[L], activation=tf.nn.relu, name="lay"+str(L))
    layers.append(layer)       
layers.append(tf.layers.Dense(n_y, activation=None))

# Here I try to get the weights
weights = [L.trainable_weights for L in layers] # Returns empty lists
weights = tf.concat(weights,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I highly recommend you defining weights and layers using the very basic operation like

```
weights = {
'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, n_hidden_1])),
'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, num_classes]))}

biases = {
'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))}
```

instead of advanced API such as `tf.layers.Dense()`. Here you have a very simple [example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/neural_network_raw.ipynb).

Then the value of `weights` can be fetched by

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    weights_value = sess.run(weights['h1'])
    print(weights_value)
```

Hope it's useful.